# Still getting error message after `except` statement dealing with `ProgrammingError`

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, error-handling

I am using python to automatically populate a MySQL DB. The script that populates the DB (`/path/to/pythonScript.py` very long) is actually called by another python script (example below) works fine and I have added a few statements that prevent me from inserting duplicated entries.

When I try to insert a duplicated entry with the script `/path/to/pythonScript.py` I get (as expected)

```
ProgrammingError: 1061 (42000): Duplicate key name 'unique_index'
```

In order to deal with that, I want to write a `try` `except` statement while calling the `/path/to/pythonScript.py` script, as shown below:

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector.errors import ProgrammingError

# Here I have already successfully connected to the DB, and populated it

try:
    get_ipython().system("ipython /path/to/pythonScript.py") # this is the script that populates the DB. It does not allow the insertion of duplicated entries
except ProgrammingError:
    print("a warning message informing that I am trying to insert a duplicated entry")
```

When I call the script for the first time, everything goes well (after all, the DB was empty). But then when I call the script for the second time (i.e. when I attempt to insert duplicated entries) I am still getting the same error `ProgrammingError: 1061 (42000): Duplicate key name 'unique_index'`

I have found [this documentation page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-errors-error.html) where they show examples on how to handle errors, though there is no example specifically on the `ProgrammingError`. In this [other documentation page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-errors-programmingerror.html) there is one example on the `ProgrammingError`, though they skipped the imports section and I am afraid I am missing something by the import (note that I don't get any error when I call `from mysql.connector.errors import ProgrammingError`)?

Answer (score 1):

You are running the other script as a distinct process. Exceptions only exist within the current process - FWIW, you could be running a shell script or a C-coded binary app instead, it would be just the same.

I kindly suggest you momentarily ditch IPython and take a couple days doing the full official Python tutorial, paying particular attention to the parts about functions and modules. Then you may want to rewrite your first script to make it a proper module with proper functions (I assume from your question and example code it's currently a plain script with everything at the top-level - but I may be wrong of course ;) ), then rewrite your calling script to import functions from the first one and call them.

Also note that that `ProgrammingError` can happen for a *whole* lot of other reasons than a duplicate key, so you MUST check the exception's code to find out which exact error happened.